# Migration of OCUnit to XCTest leads to linker error

Tags: ios, linker, xcode6, xctest

I've tried to migrate our `OCUnit` to `XCTest`. So I have 100% compilable project but I see next linker error:

```
Error:Undefined symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTestCase' referenced from:...
```

My `"Framework Search Paths"` looks like this:

```
$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks     (non-recursive)
$(inherited)                                (non-recursive)
$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)                 (non-recursive)
```

I'm not familiar what else to do to satisfy linker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the exact same error messages in Xcode 6.1 after migrating with
**Pull Down Menu** → **Edit** → **Refactor** → **Convert to XCTest**.

I got 2 solutions:

---

### Solution 1 <sup><sub>*(recreate test project)*</sub></sup>

1. Backup all source files in your test project.
2. In **Project Navigator**, select the project.
   This shows the project settings.
3. In the project settings, click **Show project and targets list**.
   [image: Show project and targets list]
4. Select the **test target**, and press <kbd>delete</kbd> to delete it.
   [image: project settings - test target]
5. In **Project Navigator**, select the **test target**, and press <kbd>delete</kbd> to delete it.
   [image: Project Navigator - test target]
6. In **Test Navigator**, click the **+** button on the bottom left, and choose **New Test Target**.
   [image: Test Navigator - New Test Target]
7. Add your original source files back into the new test target.
8. Now test your project as usual.

---

### Solution 2 <sup><sub>*(hackishly modify test project)*</sub></sup>

1. In **Project Navigator**, select the project.
   This shows the project settings.
2. In the project settings, select the **test target** (not the main target), then select **Build Phases**.
3. In **Link Binary With Libraries**, click the **+** button.
   This shows the list of frameworks, but there is no XCTest.
4. Choose a framework that you don't use at all, say, **Twitter.framework**, and click **Add**.
5. Open your project file (**something.pbxproj**) in a text editor, and replace all occurrences of **Twitter.framework** with **XCTest.framework**.
   <sub>Note: the **pbxproj** file is inside the **.xcodeproj** folder. In Finder, you have to **right click** on the .xcodeproj and select **Show Package Contents**.</sub>
6. Go back to **Link Binary With Libraries** in Xcode, and check that **XCTest.framework** is added.

   - If not, try restarting Xcode.
   - If it is added but is red, just ignore it. Xcode can't find the framework, but the linker can.
7. Now test your project as usual.